# Pandas filter dataset for M-F 8AM-4PM

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Any give me a tip for filtering a dataset to contain only data for Monday through Friday on the times of 8AM to 4PM?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(11)

rows,cols = 50000,2
data = np.random.rand(rows,cols) 
tidx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=rows, freq='H') 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Temperature','Value'], index=tidx)

#filter for time
df = df.between_time('8:00', '16:00')

#filter out weekends
df = df[(df.index.weekday < 6)]

df
```

This only seems to be Tuesdays for some reason

```
df['dayName'] = df.index.day_name()[0]

df.dayName.describe()
```

prints

```
count       16074
unique          1
top       Tuesday
freq        16074
Name: dayName, dtype: object
```

Comment: `df.index.day_name()[0]` returns a scalar 'Tuesday' a single value, just the value of the first record, now  you are setting this as a column in the dataframe.  This is not the correct way.   `df['dayName'] = df.index.day_name()`  Non need for the slicing with `[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(11)

rows,cols = 50000,2
data = np.random.rand(rows,cols) 
tidx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=rows, freq='H') 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Temperature','Value'], index=tidx)

#filter for time
df1 = df.between_time('8:00', '16:00')

#filter out weekends
df1 = df1[df1.index.weekday <= 4]

df1
```

Then, check:

```
df1.index.day_name().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Thursday     2682
Tuesday      2682
Wednesday    2682
Friday       2682
Monday       2673
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Could you ever help me with this SO post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74908952/pandas-calculating-time-deltas-from-index